# Normalization forms for a database

Tags: sql, database

so I'm pretty new to this, and I created a database model for an airport

[database Image]

[image: 1]

Could anyone please help me understand what are the normalization forms of the tables? I'm pretty confused with that concept

Comment: That link asks for a user/password. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: turns out the link can't be publicly accessed, so I just posted a screenshot of the database

Comment: remove association `reservation` to `airplane`... you don't reserve airplanes you reserve flights/seats and also remove `airplane_id` from `reservation table`

Comment: in the `flight` table you can either add the seat numbers there or create new table `flight_seats` with `reservationid` .. also seat numbers are alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

i dont wan't to post a big answer but this link should explain things in a simple to understand way:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description

> Normalization is the process of organizing data in a database. This includes creating tables and establishing relationships between those tables according to rules designed both to protect the data and to make the database more flexible by eliminating redundancy and inconsistent dependency.